# CFSSL to start with intermediate certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I am trying to setup [CFSSL](https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl) (`v1.4.1`), after following [this](https://technedigitale.com/archives/639) tutorial I have generated following files (self-sign)

```
ROOT_CA_CSR.json
intermediate_ca-key.pem
intermediate_ca.csr
intermediate_ca.pem
intermediate_ca_csr.json
root_ca-key.pem
root_ca.csr
root_ca.pem
root_to_intermediate_ca.json
```

Want to able to generate certificate using API I need to start the process with `cfssl serve -ca=ca.pem -ca-key=ca-key.pem -address=0.0.0.0"` ([Ref](https://www.greenreedtech.com/building-a-lightweight-ceritifcate-authority/)). For any device certificate generation I want to use **intermediate** key (only).

What changes I need to make in the `cfssl serve` command so cfssl generated certificates will be using intermediate key & use postgres database ?

Answer (score 1):

the command line should be as follows:

```
cfssl serve -loglevel 1 -address 0.0.0.0 -port 8888 \
    -ca-key intermediate_ca-key.pem -ca intermediate_ca.pem \ 
    -config profiles.json
    -db-config db.json
```

A basic syntax of the profiles.json file is described in the document https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl/blob/master/doc/cmd/cfssl.txt

The syntax of the db.json file is described in the https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl/blob/master/certdb/README.md file, and the DDL to create the database are available beneath the "/certdb" directory of the Github project - each db engine has a dedicated directory, so for example the DDL files for PostgreSQL are in the https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl/tree/master/certdb/pg/migrations directory

Please read carefully these security remarks:

Depending on your profiles settings, cfssl can spin up the following signing facilities:

- "sign" - a public (so no authentication at all) endpoint supporting PEM encoded ones. This is useful, since it enables you to sign with CSR generated by third parties using standard tools such as openssl, but it is a HUGE security hole since enabling anybody that can reach the cfssl endpoint can generate certificates.
- "authsign" - an authenticated endpoint (it uses a shared secret) that supports only CFSSL JSON encoded CSR

Regardless of which one of the two you are using, you must at least enable TLS to secure communications confidentiality (you are authenticating on that channel). If you need to support PEM encoded CSR and so you need the "sign" endpoint, set up cfssl to use mutual-TLS authentication.

The above two measures should be enough to mitigate the security shortcomings.

If you need to quickly learn how to set up a cfssl based PKI, you may find useful the book "[A Full-Featured PKI With Cloudflare's PKI and TLS Toolkit](https://www.lulu.com/shop/marco-antonio-carcano/a-full-featured-pki-with-cloudflares-pki-and-tls-toolkit/ebook/product-65qr2e8.html)", since it provides a "by examples" approach with full featured Labs covering the very most of the available options.

Answer (score 0):

This was helpful :

`cfssl serve -db-config=sqlite_db.json -ca=server/server.pem -ca-key=server/server-key.pem -config=config.json`

Source :
 - https://propellered.com/posts/cfssl_setting_up_ocsp_api/
 - https://propellered.com/posts/cfssl_setting_up/